# Looping a regression for different independent variable columns and lagged dependent variables in R?

Tags: r, loops, regression

I am trying to run a regression of future growth (independent var) against past new employees at different lag periods, i for i is 1:24 but I keep running into problems when running the regression. Would appreciate help with the error I am getting or any better suggestions on how to run the regression.

Since I needed to calculate future growth over a timeframe corresponding to the lag periods, I calculated and stored growth over time periods 1:24 in with column names growth_m1, growth_m2,... growth_m24 in the same data table using the below formula:

```
n <- 24
for (i in 1:n) {
  growth_data[[paste0("growth_m", i)]] <- c(growth_data$sales - lag(growth_data$sales,i))
}
```

My data looks like this:

```
newemployees growth_m1 growth_m2 growth_m3
-0.03   NA  NA  NA  
1.01    0.3 NA  NA  
0.72    0.0 0.3 NA  
-1.21   0.7 0.7 1.0 
-2.51   0.0 0.7 0.7 
2.14    0.3 0.3 1.0 
-5.66   0.0 0.3 0.3
```

Now I need to run a regression for growth_mi column against lag(growth_data$newemployees,i) and store the coefficients in a dataframe for i in 1:24. I have tried the below formula but I get an error:

```
model <- list()
for (i in 1:24){
  model[[i]] = lm(growth_data[,names(growth_data)[grepl(paste0("growth_m", i),names(growth_data))]][1] ~ lag(growth_data$newemployees,i), data=growth_data)
}
```

Error in model.frame.default(formula = growth_data[,names(growth_data)[grepl(paste0("growth_m", : invalid type (list) for variable 'growth_data[,names(growth_data)[grepl(paste0("growth_m", i),names(growth_data))]][1]'

How can I run this regression and store the data properly? I am very new to R so would appreciate any help!

Comment: Hello Abby, better if you share a sample of your data i.e. dput(growth_data) or dput(head(growth_data,10))

Answer (score 0):

Using `anscombe` which is built into R as an example (since the input was missing from the question) first create a character vector of formulas `fo` and then run each using `lapply` giving the `lm` models in `models`.  In the future please read the information at the top of the [r](/questions/tagged/r) tag page and provide a complete reproducible example.  This uses `flag` from the collapse package which is the not the same as `lag` in base R - base R `lag` does not work with ordinary vectors.  The use of `do.call` is for the purpose of showing the Call: line as shown below.  If we had just used the simpler `run_lm <- function(fo) lm(formula(fo), anscombe)` the result would be correct; however, the Call: line would literally show `formula(fo)`.

```
library(collapse) 

fo <- sprintf("y%d ~ x%d + flag(y%d)", 1:4, 1:4, 1:4)
run_lm <- function(fo) do.call("lm", list(formula(fo), quote(anscombe)))
models <- lapply(fo, run_lm)

models
```

giving

```
[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = y1 ~ x1 + flag(y1), data = anscombe)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x1     flag(y1)  
     4.7739       0.4849      -0.2138  


[[2]]

Call:
lm(formula = y2 ~ x2 + flag(y2), data = anscombe)
...snip...
```

### Note

`anscombe` lkooks like this:

```
> anscombe
   x1 x2 x3 x4    y1   y2    y3    y4
1  10 10 10  8  8.04 9.14  7.46  6.58
2   8  8  8  8  6.95 8.14  6.77  5.76
3  13 13 13  8  7.58 8.74 12.74  7.71
4   9  9  9  8  8.81 8.77  7.11  8.84
5  11 11 11  8  8.33 9.26  7.81  8.47
6  14 14 14  8  9.96 8.10  8.84  7.04
7   6  6  6  8  7.24 6.13  6.08  5.25
8   4  4  4 19  4.26 3.10  5.39 12.50
9  12 12 12  8 10.84 9.13  8.15  5.56
10  7  7  7  8  4.82 7.26  6.42  7.91
11  5  5  5  8  5.68 4.74  5.73  6.89
```